# State with IO in Haskell for CLI application

Tags: haskell, state, immutability

I am trying to write a simple implementation of the game Hangman in Haskell and one problem I have is keeping the state of the game.

A simplified / abstract version of my problem looks like this:

```
advanceState :: Char -> [Char] -> [Char]
advanceState = (:)
```

My question seems simple but I can't figure out the answer: How can I invoke this function after each character supplied via the standard input and how can I terminate the loop once a certain set of characters was read?

Note that I have also tried versions with `State [Char] a` and `StateT [Char] IO a` to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution to this problem which doesn't involve using monads besides `IO` is to use inner `loop` function which keeps its state as an argument. I'm going to provide an artificial example below:

```
myProgram :: IO [Char]
myProgram = loop []
  where
    loop :: [Char] -> IO [Char]
    loop state = do
        input <- getLine
        case input of
            "A" -> do
                putStrLn "Advancing state with A"
                loop ('A' : state)
            "B" -> do
                putStrLn "State didn't change"
                loop state
            _ -> do
                putStrLn "Finishing game"
                pure state  -- recursion ends here
```

So a combination of recursion and pattern-matching allows you to change your state depending on your input. So when you call `loop` next time, it's given a possible new `state`.

Answer (score 1):

Provided that don't know how do you to keep the state. Here just provide a simple example show how to use `StateT` with reading characters from standard input.

Firstly, to define the `advanceState` function as:

```
advanceState::StateT [Char] IO [Char]
advanceState = StateT readInput where
    readInput cs = do c <- getChar
                      let newState = (c:cs)
                      return (newState, newState)
```

The function embedded in `StateT` is `readInput`, it has type:

```
[Char]->IO ([Char], [Char])
```

The first element of pair `([Char], [Char])` is input that what we want, and the second element of that is the "state" will pass to `readInput` whenever `advanceState` is called again.

Now, below is an example show how to use `advanceState`:

```
getChar10::StateT [Char] IO [Char]
getChar10 = do s <- advanceState
               if (length s) <= 10
               then getChar10
               else do put []
                       return (reverse s)
```

This example show how to get 10 character from standard input when the user press enter, note that `put []` reset the state so that next call of `advanceState` will not has the previous input.

Finally, we can play around with them:

```
playState::IO ()
playState = print =<< evalStateT loop [] where
    loop  = do s1 <- getChar10
               s2 <- getChar10
               return (s1 ++ "::" ++ s2)
```

The `playState` function will print first 20 characters (included new line character \n, \r) whatever how many characters user has inputted before press enter. If input not enough 20 characters, `playState` will request user to input more characters.